# CIFaceFeature hasSmile is always false

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Using the following to detect faces in images:

```
var ciImage  = CIImage(CGImage:imageView.image!.CGImage)
var ciDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil,
  options: [
    CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh,
    CIDetectorSmile: true,
    CIDetectorEyeBlink: true
  ])

var features = ciDetector.featuresInImage(ciImage)

for feature:CIFaceFeature in (features as! [CIFaceFeature]) {
   println("has smile: \(feature.hasSmile)")
}
```

I ran the former code on many images. `hasSmile` always returns false.

**How do I have to configure face detection to detect smiles correctly?**

Answer (score 12):

A quick google search on "CIFaceDetector hasSmile" yields this link on [Face Smiling and Blinking detection on iOS 7](http://idevelopersmalltalk.blogspot.com/2013/10/face-smiling-and-blinking-detection-on.html)

It looks like you need to use a different form of the ciDetector.featuresInImage call. The code in Objective-C looks like this:

```
NSDictionary *options = @{ CIDetectorSmile: @(YES), CIDetectorEyeBlink: @(YES),};
NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:image options:options];
```

In Swift that would be something like this::

```
let options: [NSObject: AnyObject] = 
  [CIDetectorSmile: true, CIDetectorEyeBlink, true]
var features = ciDetector.featuresInImage(ciImage, options: options)
```